# FaceBook feed dialog share options

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

**Some Background Info**

As of Mar/Feb 2014, the Facebook sharer.php way of sharing content no longer accepts custom parameters. See [response from a Facebook engineer](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/357750474364812/?comment_id=308955395926697).

It used to allow multiple parameters in this form:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100
    &p[url]={url}
    &p[images][0]={img}
    &p[title]={title}
    &p[summary]={desc}
```

So you could override the title, image and description that facebook would scrape from the page, but it seems these are now ignored.

Instead, Facebook now favours the opengraph tags on the page.

**So why is this a problem?**

This is my scenario: I have a gallery page with multitple images. I have a lightbox that loads an image when clicked, and when the lightbox is shown, I also show share icons for all the major social networks, including facebook.

The facebook sharer url is built up using the above format, so I pass in the specific image together with the image caption. These values are now ignored.

**Feed Dialog To The Rescue?**

The [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) method of sharing is now the preferred method, and it supports passing in custom images and captions. It works perfectly in my above gallery scenario. But it has a limitation: it does not allow you to share the content on a page you manage like the sharer.php does:

[image: sharer.php share options]

**So my question is...**

How can I get the Feed Dialog to work like the sharer.php and give the end-user the option to share to a group, friend's timeline or a page he/she manages?

Comment: Can you share the timelines with sharer? :O

Comment: @SahilMittal I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: You said that you were able to share friends timeline with sharer

Comment: I still have no idea what you are saying. if you look at the above screenshot from the sharer, you will see the option to "share on a friend's timeline"

Comment: The Feed dialog does not offer that option – only the `to` parameter, but with that you would have to build your own UI to have the user chose the target prior to calling the Feed dialog. // The whole thing would be much easier, if you actually had individual URLs for each of your pictures – that way, you could provide individual OG meta information under each URL easily.

Answer (score 0):

> But it has a limitation: it does not allow you to share the content on a page you manage like the sharer.php does

It incorrect statement. You can post anywhere using the Feed Dialog! You can use the **`to`** parameter and give it the concerned id where you want to share the feed.

[For example](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?%20%20app_id=145634995501895%20%20&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption%20%20%20&link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fdialogs%2F%20%20&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer&to=301724886521492)

**PS** Facebook has introduces Graph API **v2** today, and introduced new [Share Dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) over Feed Dialogs. I'm not share if that's to your significance but you can have  a look.

Comment: the `to` parameter has to be specified in the link, which I do not want. I want to let the visitor decide where they want to share the content and not restrict them in any way - exactly how the old sharer did it

Comment: Totally agree w/ Vinnie on this.

Comment: @Sahil Mittal, hi, i have the same problem and tried the new 'Share Dialogs' as you said but it doesn't provide the options to share on page you manage , i am using custom parameters, any idea ?